# How do I replace a cable modem router with my own server as DHCP?

Tags: dns, dhcp, internet-connection, routing, dnsmasq

My ISP gave me a really crappy router-modem-combination that lacks basic features. For instance you can't assign a constant ip to the mac adress of a client PC. I run a server for my home entertainment system and a storage server. Both should have a static ip within my LAN.

So my thought was to disable the DHCP-Server on the crappy modem and let my home entertainment server do the ip assignments. I was thinking dnsmasq, but I don't seem to get it to work. I thought maybe someone can help me

**So the situation:**

`192.168.0.1` is the **server** ip in LAN, lets say its mac is `aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa` and it is connected to a switch with device `eth0`. Here it's `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.2
```

`192.168.0.2` is the ip of the **cable modem** (set statically). It is connected to the internet and the same switch as the server. mac: `bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb`

`192,168.0.3` is supposed to be the future ip of the network **storage** system, lets say its mac adress is `cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc`. It is also connected to the same switch as the other devices

**What I've done so far:**

I've installed dnsmasq on the server, stopped the service and edited `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` to look like this:

```
interface=eth0
dhcp-range=192.168.0.10,192.168.0.254,72
dhcp-host=aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa,server,192.168.0.1,infinite
dhcp-host=bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb,cable,192.168.0.1,infinite
dhcp-host=cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc,storage,192.168.0.3,infinite
```

I've edited `/etc/resolv.conf` to contain the localhost (server) and the nameservers of the ISP:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 123.321.123.321
nameserver 321.123.321.123
```

**The Problem:**

The DHCP works just fine, but for some reason dnsmasq gives the wrong gateway. It gives the server's ip instead of the gateways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I just found out about the `dhcp-option` in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
interface=eth0
dhcp-option=3,192.168.0.2
dhcp-range=192.168.0.10,192.168.0.254,72
```

That solves the problem. Sorry to bother you. Hope it will help someone else, at least!